# Android tool to check which devices are compatible

Tags: android

I have recently published an app for android. I have specified that minSdkVersion = 14. In google play console it tells me that my app supports all devices. Even so I have encountered that some devices with higher SDK than 14 got error on play store that they are not supported. Why google play console shows me that my app supports all devices then?

[image: google play console - all devices are supported]

So I wonder is there any tool that would analyze my app and show me devices that is not supported by my app - correctly (not like google play console)?

Comment: have you added <uses-feature /> tag

Comment: I have, and that is why the app can't be installed on some devices. But why google console still shows me that my app is supporting all devices? Should't it inform me about it? Why is there Excluded devices number then? Am i missing something?

I am looking for some tool that would show me how many devices are not supported by my app...